# Get time process takes to complete in seconds?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, messagebox

My program runs a batch file in cmd.exe, after it finished I want to display a MessageBox to user saying `Finished in #.## seconds`,

I'm redirecting CMD output to a textbox using `process.BeginOutputReadLine()`, this is the code I tried:

```
if (e.Data == null)
{  
    string time = process.TotalProcessorTime.Seconds.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("Finished in " + time + " seconds");
}
```

It took about 7-15 seconds to complete the process, but the MessageBox displayed `Finished in 0 seconds`.

How do I get the accurate time it took to complete in seconds?

Comment: [Use a `Stopwatch` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Comment: instead of using string concat use `string.Format` and pass in arguments using `{0}` I have provided you a simplified answer as well

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
//Do things
watch.Stop();
Text = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString();
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Alexei and DJ KRAZE's answers were also really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `process.ExitTime.Subtract(process.StartTime).TotalSeconds`?

**Edited to add:** Note that you will get an exception if you try to use this before the process has exited. Per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exittime%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for `ExitTime`, use the `HasExited` property if you have any doubt as to whether this is the case or not.

Answer (score 2):

Could you ultimately do something like this if it makes it easier to read for you

```
var procTime = DateTime.Now - Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime;
var procTimeInSec = procTime.Seconds;
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Finished in {0} seconds", procTimeInSec));
```

to access you may want to change the two `var local variables to be accessible from outside the local scope.

below is how you would declare it outside of the local method at the top of the Class

```
   public static TimeSpan procTime = new TimeSpan();
   var procTimeInSec, can still be declared in the local scope
```

Comment: Can't access ProcTime in my event, since it's declared in another method.

Comment: Can't you store the process Start time in a member variable..? can you clarify and or show how it's being declared currently this may help in solving your issue.. also `Process.GetCurrentProcess` should be accessible throughout the application..procTime in my example is local scope. I will edit and explain what each type var variable should be explicitly declared as

Comment: I have a button1.Click event that starts the Process, I was declaring the var in there, then I am redirecting the cmd output asynchronously to a textbox, so in the event process.OutputDatReceived, after e.Data == null, I'm calling the MessageBox with the time it took to complete.

Comment: you need to declare it outside the Button Click and Assign it inside the button click.. meaning at the class level you can declare a Static Variable , Public, Private...etc.. look at the example it works I tested it once you assign it.. the static variable in my example you can access it..

Answer (score 1):

Just basic [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) should be enough.

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

// run external process, if asynchronous - 
//store stopWatch in member variable instead of local

stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Note that [TotalProcessorTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.totalprocessortime.aspx) measures CPU usage time, which could very well be 0 seconds for CMD.exe as it really does not do much.

Comment: Perfect, but is there any way to remove the milliseconds? I just want whole seconds.

Comment: @Abraham - [TimeSpan.TotalSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds.aspx) is probably what you want than. Check out [formatting options for `TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx) too as it may do exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class.  You'll need to start the stopwatch before your process begins, then stop it afterwards and get the elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Stopwatch class when starting the process.

On the process, add an event handler for the Exited event and when the process is done, stop the stopwatch and retrieve the time.

```
class Foo
{
   Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

   public void RunProcess(Process process)
   {
      process.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcessExit);

      process.Start();
      watch.Start();
   }

   public void ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      watch.Stop();
   }
}
```